# TypeError: 'StringMethods' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, pandas

I want to retreive the value from a dataframe column "age" data type as "Object".
Age is in frequency for e.g, 10-20, 20-30.

I want to keep the upper end of the range.for e.g 20,30 etc.

I tried below logic:

```
df['age'] = df['age'].astype(str)
df['age'] = df['age'].str[1:].str.split('-', expand = True)[0]
df['age'] = df['age'].astype(int)
```

But getting the error as

> "TypeError: 'StringMethods' object is not subscriptable"

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: can you show the dtypes of your df through df.dtypes?
In the second statement, if I understand correctly you are trying to get the first element from the list i.e [10, 20] in which case expand should be False

Comment: `df['age'] = df['age'].str.extract('(\d+)-')[0].astype(int)` would also work

Comment: @QuangHoang Thank you, it works.

Comment: @emiljoj age 101766 non-null object; even after expand as False, it gives the same error. I am trying to get the second element from [10,20), I want to retrieve 20.

Comment: [10, 20) seems of dtype Interval. Would following also work? 
df['Age'].apply(lambda x: x.right)

Answer (score 1):

I think you need:

```
df["age"] = df["age"].str.split("-").str[1]
```